# Rails routes map incorrectly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have the following statement in routes:

```
  resource :users, :only => [:index, :show, :update, :destroy] do
    get "users/dashboard"
  end
```

However, when I do rake routes, I got:

```
dashboard_users GET    /users/users/dashboard(.:format)       users/users#dashboard
               users GET    /users(.:format)                       users#show
                     PUT    /users(.:format)                       users#update
                     DELETE /users(.:format)                       users#destroy
```

Note that users_path was incorrectly mapped to users#show. I was expecting:

```
users GET    /users/:id/(.:format)                       users#show
```

What might cause this issue and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `resources` instead of `resource`. e.g.

```
resources 'users'
```

the difference between resource and resources is:

resource is for operations for a single model. when using `resource model`,   there's no "index" action.

see: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

further more, I notice that your route is a bit strange. if you just want to add an action named 'dashboard' with GET accessing method, just declare like this:

```
resources 'users' do 
  get :dashboard
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this

```
resource :users, :only => [:index, :show, :update, :destroy] do
  get "users/dashboard"
end
```

Do this

```
namespace :dashboard do 
    resource :users, :only=>[:index,:show,:udpate,:destroy]
end
```

I think this will work for you.